# Java code not getting linked to mysql file on server, any settings on C-panel?

Tags: cpanel

How to link java code with mssql on c-panel. For eg U/N & P/W login details going into mysql database offline on tomcat. But once uploaded on server, code not getting linked to database. May be something to do with C-Panel settings :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed/configured Tomcat on your cPanel server. If it is installed, you should add the following lines in .htaccess file:

> SetHandler jakarta-servlet
>
> SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13

Answer (score 0):

on your connection string, are you sure you added the correct IP address including Port , database port, user , pass ?

Comment: We are getting null pointer exception error msg (searchdaoimp.java:30) which is corresponding to the connection string. Our connection seetings ar as follows: 
Host= 'ip add of the server' 
Database =database name 
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database name  
User=database username  
Password=database password
MySql connectionPort ='3306'
Project working offlineon local computer via following settings:
Driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/muhealdb
User=****
Password=****